# Docker Push Container to Azure ACR "unauthorized: authentication required"

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

What is going on here?  This should work.

```
$ az logout
$ az login
To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code FW....C to authenticate.
[
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "homeTenantId": "[redacted]",
    "id": "[redacted]",
    "isDefault": true,
    "managedByTenants": [],
    "name": "Azure subscription 1",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "[redacted]",
    "user": {
      "name": "[redacted]",
      "type": "user"
    }
  }
]
$ az account set -s [subscription id redacted]
$ az acr login --name arcticacr
Login Succeeded
$ docker push ArcticaCR.azurecr.io/sftp01/sftptest:0.02
The push refers to a repository [ArcticaCR.azurecr.io/sftp01/sftptest]
b152ea134f5f: Preparing 
d799cb5f12bf: Preparing 
6b4e8c931236: Preparing 
6f4c91ca60bd: Preparing 
86eecfa8066e: Preparing 
unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information.
```

I'm logged in as the owner of this registry (per IAM).  I should be authorized to do anything.  Admin user is enabled under Access keys, even though I'm not using those.

Answer (score 1):

The image name needs to be in all lowercase.  You can't just change the push command to lowercase.

```
$ docker build -t arcticacr.azurecr.io/sftp01/sftptest:0.02 -f Dockerfile .
$ az login
$ az acr login --name arcticacr
$ docker push arcticacr.azurecr.io/sftp01/sftptest:0.02
```